# Calling a method from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver that is responding to repeating Alarmanager broadcast.  An object for the broadcast receiver is created in another class, but I need the Onreceive method of the broadcast receiver to call a method inside the class that creates the object.

So to try to make this clearer.  Class B is a broadcast receiver.  Inside Class A, I instantiate an object of Class B.  But the OnRecieve method needs to class a public method of Class A.

BTW, Class A is the Mainactivity class.

I was thinking of trying passing a Runnable object as a parameter in the setup of Class B but I am not totally sure how to implement that.

```
public class TimerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        CalcDisplay(true);      
    }

    public void setTimer(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60, pi);
    }

    public void cancelTimer(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(Sender);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your receiver (class B) inside of your Activity (class A). Like so:

```
public class A extends Activity {

    B receiver = new B();

    ...*Some stuff*

    public class B extends BroadCastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive() {
            *call method from class A*
        }

    }
}
```

Now class B will have access to class A's methods.

Comment: I tried that but the OnReceive is never called.  I want to post my code but I am not sure how to get it formatted correctly on here.

Comment: Your comments keep appearing and disappearing, it's confusing me lol. I saw the one with the code in it, then it vanished... Edit your original post and paste it in there. Indent it to put it in a code block.

Comment: Alright, I see it now. I think the main issue is that your intent is pointing to your activity class instead of your receiver class. Change that and see if it works.

But also: are these methods inside of your receiver? If so, why? I think it's more appropriate for them to go in the Activity. And you should probably set a flag for the PendingIntent, rather than just 0. I'm not terribly familiar with PendingIntents but that might be part of the problem too.

Comment: Ok my setTimer function now looks like this and is in my MainActivity class:  ` public void setTimer(Context context)
 {
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.TimerBroadcastReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60, pi);
 }
`  It still does not call the OnReceive.  What should the Receiver Tag in the Manifest look like?

Comment: Are you using any intent filters? If not, then <receiver android:name="your.package.name.TimerBroadcastReceiver" ></receiver> should do it.

Comment: Aha... do you still have these methods inside your receiver class? If so, then this applies to you: [BroadcastReceiver Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle). Particularly: "A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active." So if you're trying to call those methods from a receiver object, it's not going to work. You have to put them outside of the receiver.

Comment: No I put the setTimer and Cancel timer in the main activity class.  I also added my package name before TimerBroadcastReceiver in the Manifest and that didn't fix it either.   Then I changed it to my-package.name.MainActivity.TimerBroadcastReceiver and that didn't fix it.  I do appreciate all your help, you have been great!

Comment: I took a break from this project for a while.  I am still having this issue.  If I next the BroadcastReceiver inside my main activity class, the OnReceive method never is called.  Anyone have any ideas?